# On continuity of the sum of a series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Consider the function $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$, defined by $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}& (x,y)\neq (0,0\\
0& (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$ and

$g(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f((x-n),(y-n))}{2^n}$. Which of the following statements are true?

$1$. $g$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2$.

$2$. $g$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2\setminus (k,k),k\in\Bbb N$.

$3$. $g(c,y)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ for each fixed $c$.

I am trying $M_n$-test for series of $g$ as function $f$ is bounded, but I am confused about series of functions of two variables. I  only studied about series of single variable functions. It seems that answer will be options $2$nd and $3$rd but don’t know how . Please help . Thank you in advance.

Comment: notice that $ f(x,y) \leq 1$ since $2xy \leq x^2+y^2 \iff (x-y)^2 \geq 0$ which is true. You can now apply the Weierstrass M test

Comment: @fGDu94 $M$-test  is valid for multivariable functions?

Comment: yes it is valid

Comment: @fGDu94 under uniform convergence can i say that discontinuous points goes to discontinuous point so that I can remove $(k,k)$? Thank you .

Comment: @fGDi94 if it becomes continuous at these points also then first option become true . So this point is remaining.

Comment: it must be $2$ because $g(x,y)$ will be discontinuous at $(k,k)$ since $f$ is not continuous at zero. You can see this by taking the limit of $f$ to zero along different paths.

Comment: @fGDu94 Careful with Weierstrass, we want $|f(x,y)|\le 1.$

Comment: pretty sure we also have $|f(x,y)| \leq 1$

Comment: @zhw sir if possible can you give solution? Thank you.

Comment: To prove bounded ness we can you polar form also ....

Comment: @zhw. can help to prove discontinuous at points $(k,k)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. To show $g$ is discontinuous at $(1,1),$ note

$$g(x,y) = \frac{f(x-1,y-1)}{2} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{f((x-n),(y-n))}{2^n}.$$

The first term on the right is discontinuous at $(1,1)$ while the remaining sum is continuous at $(1,1)$ by Weierstrass.

2. Let $E=\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(n,n):n\in \mathbb N\}.$ Then each summand in the series defining $g$ is continuous everywhere on $E.$ Use Weierstrass.
3. Note $f$ is continuous on each vertical line. Thus each summand defining $g$ is continuous on each vertical line. Weierstrass then shows $g$ is continuous on each vertical line.

Comment: Now I got . Thank you very much .